# Atomic reads and writes of properties

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, properties

This question has been asked before but i still don't understand it fully so here it goes.

If i have a class with a property (a non-nullable double or int) - can i read and write the property with multiple threads?

I have read somewhere that since doubles are 64 bytes, it is possible to read a double property on one thread while it is being written on a different one.  This will result in the reading thread returning a value that is neither the original value nor the new written value.

When could this happen? Is it possible with ints as well? Does it happen with both 64 and 32 bit applications?

I haven't been able to replicate this situation in a console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i have a class with a property (a non-nullable double or int) - can i read and write the property with multiple theads?

I assume you mean "without any synchronization".

`double` and `long` are both 64 *bits* (8 bytes) in size, and are *not* guaranteed to be written atomically. So if you were moving from a value with byte pattern ABCD EFGH to a value with byte pattern MNOP QRST, you could *potentially* end up seeing (from a different thread) ABCD QRST or MNOP EFGH.

With properly aligned values of size 32 bits or lower, atomicity is guaranteed. (I don't remember seeing any guarantees that values *will* be properly aligned, but I believe they are by default unless you force a particular layout via attributes.) The C# 4 spec doesn't even mention alignment in section 5.5 which deals with atomicity:

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

Additionally, atomicity isn't the same as volatility - so without any extra care being taken, a read from one thread may not "see" a write from a different thread.

Comment: But my understanding is that this is bc in 32 bit apps, the program can only process half of the variable at a time - so if i am running a 64 bit app, would doubles then be safe?

Comment: @William: In a 64-bit process I *believe* it would be atomic. But you'd still have the issue of stale reads. Unless you *genuinely* don't care about seeing data written by another thread, I'd use the `Interlocked` class or a lock.

Comment: For my application I really don't think stale reads will be an issue - is there a way that I could replicate this situation so that I can confirm whether running it in 64-bit will be atomic?

Comment: @William: The CLI spec makes this guarantee: "A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size (the size of type native int) is atomic (see §12.6.2) when all the write accesses to a location are the same size." - but I don't know what alignment is guaranteed. Note that you could easily find it hard to replicate the non-atomicity anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These operations are not atomic, that's why the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class exists in the first place, with methods like `Increment(Int32)` and `Increment(Int64)`.

To ensure thread safety, you should use at least this class, if not more complex locking (with `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, for example, in case you want to synchronize access to groups of properties).

Comment: So are you disagreeing with the Jon (above) and saying that ints are not thread safe?

Comment: It's not that I'm disagreeing or not. Jon explained the theoretical aspects of atomic read/writes on built-in data types. I'm saying that, in practice, you need to use `Interlocked` or any other sync mechanism in order to avoid the special cases and exceptions Jon described below.